# Array of dictionary in php

Tags: php, push-notification, push

How to put below value in PHP:

```
{     "aps": 
          {          "badge": 10,          
                     "alert": "Hello world!",         
                     "sound": "cat.caf"     
          },    
      "job_id": 1 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to search it?

Comment: Why you don't Google first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you will build your array like this

```
$data =  array( 'aps'=>array(
                     'badge'=> 10,          
                     'alert'=> 'Hello world!',         
                     'sound'=> 'cat.caf'                           
                       ),
                'job_id'=> 1
              );

echo json_encode($data);
```

---

Output

```
{
    "aps": {
        "badge": 10,
        "alert": "Hello world!",
        "sound": "cat.caf"
    },
    "job_id": 1
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/127136)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<?
  $json = <<<JSON
{ "aps": { "badge": 10,
"alert": "Hello world!",
"sound": "cat.caf"
},
"job_id": 1 }
JSON;

  $data = json_decode($json,true);
?>
```

You can access your data like `$data['aps']['badge'];` or `$data['job_id'];`.

Let me know if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's like JSON. You can use 2 functions:
[JSON encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [JSON decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)